# Is there any way to prevent this recursive function to add the initial number at the total

Tags: python

I am trying to make a recursive function that returns the sum of numbers that are divisible by four, but excluding the number itself from the total, e.g
`print(divFour(8))` should give me 4 but not 12, and `print(divFour(9))` should resut to 12.

```
def divFour(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return n % 4 + divFour(n-1) 

print(divFour(8))
```

`print(divFour(8))` == `4` ;
`print(divFour(7))` == `4` ;
`print(divFour(9))` == `12`

Comment: It would probably be easier to write *two* functions for this, an internal recursive helper and an external wrapper.

Comment: Yes that's true, i just was trying to do it in one function.

Comment: Should it be necessarily recursive? Can't it be iterative?

Comment: `divFour(4) = 6`, and subtracting 4 doesn't provide correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below code:

```
def divFour(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        res = n-1 if (n-1)%4 == 0 else 0
        return res + divFour(n-1)

print(divFour(9))
```

**Output:**

```
12
```

Comment: This `res = n-1 if (n-1)%4 == 0 else 0` was the trick. thanks

Comment: Welcome. Please consider upvoting too! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `for` loop with `range`:

```
def div_k(n, k=4):
    val = 0
    for i in range(n):
        val += i * (i % k == 0)
    return val

res = div_k(8)  # 4
res = div_k(9)  # 12
```

Alternatively, you can use a generator. The nested function structure is purely so that you don't have to call `sum` *outside* `div_k`.

```
def div_k(n, k=4):
    def div_gen(n, k):
        for i in range(n):
            yield i * (i % k == 0)
    return sum(div_gen(n, k))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, you actually do not need any recursion to compute this. You can just use math:

```
def divFour(n):
    div = (n-1) // 4
    return 4 * div*(div+1)/2
```